# git clone : This application requires one of the following versions of .NET Framework: .NET framework,Version =v4.7.2

Tags: .net, windows, windows-8, git-for-windows

I am trying to git clone from the remote repository to my local repository. whenever I enter
the git clone command and enter my username and password I am getting the following error.

This application requires one of the following versions of .NET Framework: .NET framework, Version =v4.7.2

My windows version is : 8

My current .NET version is : 4.6.01055

My suspect is git credential manager is causing this issue.

Is there any way to upgrade .NET framework version to v4.7.2 from 4.6.01055  on windows 8?

Comment: Username password in where? Do you mind sharing a screenshot please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this is because Git for Windows by default uses the credential helper Git Credential Manager Core to handle credentials.  This program requires .NET 4.7.2.

However, you're using an operating system that hasn't been supported or received security updates for over five years, and it doesn't provide this.  The best solution is to upgrade to a supported OS, which will both provide the functionality you need and prevent your system from being compromised (and therefore a hazard to the Internet).

Otherwise, you can try to use `git config --unset-all credential.helper` and then run `git config credential.helper wincred`, which will use the older `wincred` credential helper.  However, you may still find that Git is broken in many ways because nobody tests things on an obsolete OS, in addition to the security problems you have now.

Comment: What beautifully explained . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can upgrade .Net to 4.8 if you are able to upgrade to Windows 8.1 first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-8-1

Otherwise .Net 4.6 is the latest that Windows 8 supports:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-8